# How to ramp up and ramp down the test plan using selenium/WebDriver in JMeter

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter, load-testing

I am executing the test plan using **selenium/webdriver sampler** in JMeter using **concurrency Thread Group**. I want the real pacing of test plan means First I want to set the `ramp-up` for supposing 10 users and after delayed 10 seconds, I want to `ramp-down` the users just for getting the graceful termination of the test plan. Can anyone help me to achieve this type of scenario using JMeter?

> My test Plan looks like this:

[image: iu]

Currently, the problem is it's only picked the `webdriver sampler 1`and executes for the 10 users and after that, the rest of the samplers isn't picked by the thread group and it has been showing the report of only `webdriver sampler 1` for 10 users.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can easily and visually implement ramp-down using the Concurrency Thread Group, theoretically it's possible but it will require introducing [Timers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers) and it will require some extra work to come down with the appropriate sleep times distribution.

I would rather recommend considering switching to the [Ultimate Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/) instead where you either have `Shutdown Time` for a single schedule item or you can add multiple schedule items if your workload is more comples:

[image]

More information: [How to Ramp Down in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-ramp-down-on-jmeter)

Comment: Actually, I have used the selenium/webdriver samplers in my thread group. So, Is it okay to replace the thread group with ultimate thread group? I am asking this question because earlier I have tried it with the Ultimate Thread group also but it has taken the only first selenium/web driver sampler and discard the other ones. So can you please tell me why it takes the first sampler and discards the other ones?